# dataframe get average of a column based on other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

have a df with values

df

```
name    maths  english   chemistry     
 

mark     10       0         20             
tom      10       20        30             
hall     0        25        15
```

how to take average marks of the each user without considerding the value 0 in it.

expected output

```
name    maths  english   chemistry     average marks
 

mark     10       0         20             15
tom      10       20        30             30
hall     0        25        15             20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value you want to ignore to `nan` and then calculate the mean. This can be done by `df.replace({0: pd.NA})` as exemplified by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "math": {"mark": 10, "tom":10, "hall": 0}, 
    "english": {"mark":0, "tom": 20,"hall":25},
    "chemistry": {"mark":20, "tom":30, "hall":15}
})
df["average_marks"] = df.replace({0: pd.NA}).mean(axis=1)
df
```

Outputs:

```
      math  english  chemistry  average_marks
mark    10        0         20           15.0
tom     10       20         30           20.0
hall     0       25         15           20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the zero values, before computing your average :

```
df.assign(average_marks=df.mask(df.eq(0)).select_dtypes("number").mean(1))


    name    maths   english chemistry   average_marks
0   mark    10         0       20         15.0
1   tom     10        20       30         20.0
2   hall    0         25       15         20.0
```

@trimvi's solution is simpler though. This is only an alternative.